# Java - Overriding Object Type Parameter With Concrete Type

Tags: java

**EDIT:** I will leave this here as an example. Read the comments for more information but generally: DON'T USE THIS DESIGN! It's BAD!

I searched for an answer for a while now, but couldn't find anything really specific saying, no you can't because... or yes you can that's how you do it..

So the question is, Can I create an abstract method defining Object type parameters and then have something implement it with a concrete Type of parameter like this:

```
public abstract class ToBeOverriden {
    public Object method1 (Object parameter);
    public String method2 (Object parameter);
    public void method3 (Object parameter);
}
```

And then override it with this:

```
public class Implementation {
    @Override
    public DateTime method1 (Person parameter){
        return new DateTime();
    }

    @Override
    public String method2 (MotorCycle parameter){
        return new DateTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void method3 (String parameter){
        return new DateTime();
    }
}
```

Where Person is an object created by me. Return Type can be whatever. Currently I can't do this. It doesn't let me. My guess is that this is because my Class doesn't extend Object. Although everything extends Object... So...

Or do I need to refresh my Java knowledge? :)

EDIT: Added a more complex class structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You would need to use [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html):

```
public abstract class ToBeOverriden<E,V> {
    public E method (V parameter);
}

public class Implementation extends ToBeOverriden<DateTime,Person> {
    @Override
    public DateTime method (Person parameter){
        return new DateTime();
    }
}
```

**Added:**

`E` parameter can be ommited, the code will still compile. However, if different implementations of the `ToBeOverriden` will use different return types, I think it's better to retain `E`. But that's a matter of personal taste - I don't like seeing `Object` anywhere in code.

**Added 2:**

As about your update in the question, you would need to have a separate Generic type for every method. For example:

```
public abstract class ToBeOverriden<A,B,C> {
    public Object method1 (A parameter);
    public String method2 (B parameter);
    public void method3 (C parameter);
}
```

However, usually, when you need such a horrible structure - then your code is designed the wrong way. In 95% cases 1 generic type parameter is enough. In 4.99% cases 2 generic type parameters are enough.

Comment: The *E* is not required, only *V* is necessary.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh You are right, didn't think that through. Updated my answer.

Comment: What if it has more then one return type / parameter type? What will E then be?

Comment: @Hannibal I didn't understand your comment. Can you give some example (update the question maybe)?

Comment: So I guess if I have something implementing something like this, having multiple parameter types, that wouldn't be a real abstract method then, right? Because it would NOT be generic, and it couldn't be used really well. Right?

Comment: @Hannibal Yes, it won't. You should probably post your original problem (the one you are trying to deal with by using this abstract class) in a separate question and people will try to figure out how to design your code properly. Big chance you don't need generics nor abstract classes at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
public abstract class ToBeOverriden<T> {
    public Object method (T parameter);
}

public class Implementation extends ToBeOVerriden<Person>{
    @Override
    public DateTime method (Person parameter){
        return new DateTime();
    }
}
```

But you can't do that without generification, and the problem is the argument, not the return type. Suppose you could do that without generification, then you could hold a reference to your implementation object with an interface, and you could call the method with any object as argument, not just a Person (which is against Java's type-safety).

Answer (score 0):

You do :) [The spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2) says:

> Two methods have the same signature if they have the same name and argument
>   types.

You can easily have `public Object method (Object parameter);` and `public Object method (Person parameter);` in your class side by side, and these will be different methods.

And yes, all classes ultimately extend `Object`.